# Remove newline/carriage return characters in Netsuite String

Tags: sql, freemarker, netsuite

I need to remove some empty lines from one string in Netsuite.

For various reasons, it's okay for the string to remain as-is within Netsuite, but I need to format it correctly for the Advanced PDF/HTML Templates.

At the moment on the transaction forms AND the PDF/HTML templates, `{description}` can (but doesn't always) show up as;

```
Item General description

additional item notes

additional decoration

customization notes
```

What I need to do is trim this output (either in SQL on the forms, or in freemarker for the templates), so that `{description}` would then show;

```
Item General description
additional item notes
additional decoration
customization notes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
${description?replace("<br /><br />", "<br />")}
```

Comment: It's perhaps safer to do with `?replace("(<br */?>){2}", "<br />", "r")`, as that works with `<br/>` and `<br>` as well.